# React Component Library: Unexpected identifier 'Template'. Expected '}' to end an object literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, rollup

I am building my first react component library. For this I used [this template](https://github.com/HarveyD/react-component-library). This is the [current state of my library](https://github.com/simibac/react-component-library).

I can run the story book with `yarn storybook` and everything works as expected.

Also I can build and publish to the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-component-library-test-simibac).

Now, when I integrate this react component library in a new react app, I get the following error:

[image]

Since my experience is rather limited with rollup, webpack, etc, it is hard to pinpoint where the error is.

The error most likely is in the bundeling phase since it works perfectly fine with storybook, right? any ideas what might cause the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the library `uuid` was not listed as a dependency.